# 400 Bad request, PUT create Url, Api Copyleaks

Tags: python, copyleaks-api

when trying to create a new scan through a URL it is giving `400 bad request error`, accusing that the URL field is mandatory. But I send all the data when I run the postman send correctly.

Print return request:`"{u'url': [u'The url field is required.']} 400"`

Follow my code:

```
def creat_url(self, prova): 
    urlPUT = 'https://api.copyleaks.com/v3/education/submit/url/%s' % (prova)

    headers = {
      Consts.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER: self.token.generateAuthrizationHeader(),          
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    }

    varUrl = "http://my_address/completed/%s" % (prova)
    data = {
        "url": varUrl,
        "properties": {
        "webhooks": {
            "status": varUrl,
            },
        },
    }
    print(data)

    # data_json = json.dumps(data)        
    response = requests.put(urlPUT, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(response.json())
    print(response.status_code)

    if (response.status_code == Consts.HTTP_SUCCESS):
        return response.json()
    else:
        raise CommandFailedError(response)
```

Comment: I solved it using Dump, and removing the print that was giving an error (result.json ())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Content-type': 'application/json'
```

That header promises to send json data, but you aren't actually doing that.

Use `json=data` instead of `data=data` in the `requests.put()` call.

Comment: I tested this possibility and the error was the same

Comment: I solved it using Dump, and removing the print that was giving an error (result.json ())